# Discord Python Bot - Adding reactions at the same time

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord.py bot that runs a trivia game.  The bot currently adds all the reactions 1 by 1 in order, thus not tracking reactions correctly if users react before all reactions are loaded.  I know other bots send all reactions at once without load time.  How can I achieve the same thing here?

This is the snippet:

```py
question_message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

# Add delay to reactions being added to question embed.
await asyncio.sleep(5)

# Create a list of emojis to react with
emojis = [f"{i+1}\N{combining enclosing keycap}" for i in range(len(answers))] + ["\N{CHEQUERED FLAG}"]

# Use asyncio.gather to add all reactions concurrently
await asyncio.gather(*(question_message.add_reaction(emoji) for emoji in emojis))

reacted_users = {}  # Dictionary to store users who have reacted

# Adjusted check_reaction function
def check_reaction(reaction, user):
    if user == bot.user:
        return False
    if reaction.message.id != question_message.id:
        return False
    if reaction.emoji == "\N{CHEQUERED FLAG}":  # Ignore the flag emoji reactions
        return False
    if user.id in reacted_users:
        return False
    # Check for tournament mode
    if mode == "tourney" and user.id not in participants:
        return False
    reacted_users[user.id] = True  # Register user as having reacted
    # Check that the game is still active for this channel
    return ctx.channel.id in trivia_manager.active_games

def check_message(message):
    if mode == "tourney" and message.author.id not in trivia_manager.active_game_users[ctx.channel.id]:
        return False
    # Check that the game is still active for this channel
    return message.author == ctx.author and message.content.lower() == "skip" and ctx.channel.id in trivia_manager.active_games

timeout_duration = reaction_timeout
```

I tried to replace that section with the `asyncio.gather()` method to attempt adding all reactions at the same time.

I replaced:

```py
reaction_tasks = [question_message.add_reaction(f"{i+1}\N{combining enclosing keycap}") for i in range(len(answers))]
await gather(*reaction_tasks)
await question_message.add_reaction("\N{CHEQUERED FLAG}")  # Adding flag emoji
```

With:

```py
# Create a list of emojis to react with
emojis = [f"{i+1}\N{combining enclosing keycap}" for i in range(len(answers))] + ["\N{CHEQUERED FLAG}"]

# Use asyncio.gather to add all reactions concurrently
await asyncio.gather(*(question_message.add_reaction(emoji) for emoji in emojis))
```

Comment: I haven't seen bots send multiple reactions at once, I'm not sure that it's possible. However, you could try checking the reactions once the bot is done adding them to see if anyone's added a reaction while it was adding.

Comment: Can you add the code part where you is waiting for the reactions?